# Cannot read property 'NaN' of undefined at Audio.playnxt

Tags: javascript, nan

I'm getting the following error when I try to play the next song in the array list on end of the currently playing song.

```
*LocalException: TypeError: Cannot read property 'NaN' of undefined at Audio.playnxt* 
[as __zone_symbol__ON_PROPERTYended] (http://localhost:4200/main.js:484:44) at Audio.wrapFn (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:1231:43) at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:412:35) at Object.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:53332:33) at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:411:40) at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:180:51) at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:493:38) at invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:1634:18) at Audio.globalZoneAwareCallback (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:1660:21)
i: NaN
this: audio
Closure (./src/app/listenn-read/listenn-read.component.ts)
ListennReadComponent: class ListennReadComponent
ListennReadComponent_a_3_Template: ƒ ListennReadComponent_a_3_Template(rf, ctx)
_Shared_track_model__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__: Module
track: (...)
Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Module"
__esModule: true
get track: ƒ ()
__proto__: Object
_angular_core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__: Module {…}
_c0: Array(1)
0: "test"
length: 1
```

Here's the code:

```js
listenlist:track[];
audioObj=new Audio();
arrpla:number;
len:number=0;    //length of array calculates in constructor
constructor() {
    this.listenlist=[new track('chapter1','chp1name','./assets/C1.mp3'),
                     new track('chapter2','chp2name','./assets/C2.mp3'),
                     new track('chapter3','chp3name','./assets/C3.mp3')]
    this.len=this.listenlist.length;
}

play(url) {
    this.audioObj.src=url;
    this.audioObj.load();
    this.audioObj.play();
    this.audioObj.onended=this.playnext;   //calling the next function to play the next song in the list on end of the currently running song
}

playnxt() {
    var i=this.arrplaa; // i is NaN here
    i=i+1;
    if(i>=this.len){
        i=0;
    }
    this.arrpla=i;
    this.audioObj.src=this.listenlist[i].url; // this is where the exception happens
    this.audioObj.load();
    this.audioObj.play();
}
```

Comment: sounds like a missing parseInt? How is i interpreted? As string?

Comment: `var i=this.arrplaa;` - where do you define what `arrplaa` is? `i=i+1;` NaN + 1 is still NaN

Comment: `var i=( this.arrplaa > 0 ? this.arrpla : 0);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing is, you need to initialize `arrpla` (presumably to 0): instead of

```
arrpla:number;
```

do

```
arrpla = 0;
```

(The type will be inferred).

But I see another potential problem: the `this` binding. I'm afraid that here

```
this.audioObj.onended=this.playnext;
```

the `this` binding of `playnext` can be lost. So you could get `undefined + 1 makes NaN` either because `arrpla` is never defined, or because the callback doesn't get the correct `this` object.

I would convert your methods to arrow functions: replace

```
playnxt() {
```

with

```
playnxt = () => {
```

Comment: Thank you so much.it worked .I have been behind this issue from 1 week .                            Is there any othe places we could use this kind of arrow functioning(not in this issue).Any documentation on this?

Answer (score 0):

At line number 3 of your code you declared

```
arrpla:number;
```

**arrpla** is currently `undefined`

and when you do `var i=this.arrplaa;` `i` is **undefined** too.
In javascript `undefined+1` becomes `NaN` so `i=i+1` can be seen as

```
i=undefined + 1 // NaN
```

so what can you do here is initialize `arrpla to 0` using

```
arrpla:number=0;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried this,but it didn't work.The problem was with the this binding.                    
         Thank you so much for letting me know one main aspect of declaring variable that I was not aware before.